# How can independent processes running on the same Ubuntu Machine communicate with each other?

Tags: linux, ipc, inter-process-communicat

This question is meant to be language and connection method independent. Actually finding methods is the question.
I know that I can directly pipe two processes through a call like `prog1 | prog2` in the shell, and I've read something about RPC and Sockets. But everything was a little too abstract to really get a grip on it. For example it's not clear to me, how the sockets are created and if each process needs to create a socket or if many processes can use the same socket to transfer messages to each other or if I can get rid of the sockets completely.

Can someone explain how Interprocess-Communication in Linux really works and what options I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pipe**

In a producer-consumer scenario, you can use pipes, it's an IPC. A pipe is just what the name suggest, it connects a sink and a source together. In he shell the source is the standard output and the sink the standard input, so cmd1 | cmd2 just connects the output of cmd1 to the input of cmd2.

Using a pipe, it creates you two file descriptors. You can use one for the sink and the other one for the source. Once the pipe is created, you fork and one process uses one oof the file descriptor while the other one uses the other.

**Other IPC**

IPCs are various: pipe (in memory), named pipe (through a file), socket, shared memory, semaphore, message queue, signals, etc. All have pro's and con's. There are a lot of litterature online and in books about them. Describing them all here would be difficult.

Basically you have to understand that each process has it's own memory, separated from other processes. So you need to find shared resources through which to exchange data. A resource can be "physical" like a network (for socket) or mass storage (for files) or "abstract" like a pipe or a signal.

Comment: I made i a community wiki, so if anyone has time/knowledge they can make it even more detailed :)

Comment: +1 Great summary. With keywords like that I can google more. If you know more about the topic, maybe you also have an answer for a followup question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736396/softwaredevelopment-patterns-for-files-and-caches-as-inter-process-communication

Comment: I did propose an answer just now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If one of the process is producer and other is a consumer then you can go for shared memory communication. You need a semaphore for this. One process will lock the semaphore then write to the shared memory and other will lock the semaphore and read the value. Since you use semaphore dirty reads/writes will be taken care.

Comment: Processes do not share memory. So 'shared memory communication' is not possible.

Comment: Also, 'shared memory communication' (between threads of the same process), is not used only for 'producer-consumer' problems.

Comment: Shared memory can be used for communication across processes. Please refer this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-spunix_sharedmemory/index.html

Comment: So you are referring to http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open - i.e. 'POSIX Shared Memory'. I suggest you reword your answer and put that in. The way it is worded right now is confusing (at least to me).

Comment: OK. Looks like there are several other ways to achieve this (apart from 'POSIX Shared Memory'). So what you say is fine. So my only question now is about why, as you said, they can only be used for producer-consumer problems.

Comment: @Raghuram: I upvoted your answer not because it quite helpful, but because it greatly helps getting a discussion started. I still hope, that you rewrite your answer more clearly and add references, though.

Comment: @ArjunShankar shared memory is a concept introduced by SUN Microsystem on SunOS (now Solaris, and property of Oracle). This concept was adopted by most (if not all) Unix and Unix-like, including Linux. So on Linux there is really such concept as shared memory, and there are even two APIs: the IPC (SUN heritage) and the POSIX. So it is not necessary to reword the answer as this is not confusing to Unix and Linux developers.

Comment: @Huygens - I already said so in my last comment, in case you missed it. My only remaining question was w.r.t. the point about this being useful in 'producer-consumer' cases. Shared memory is more 'general' than that.